# Google Analytics Regex Code

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm having trouble figuring out the last part of my regex code for Google Analytics.  I want to be able to grab any URL from my site that fits the following pattern:

www.site.com/hotel/[any text]/rooms?[any text]

So the URLs will always begin with /hotels  and will always end with /rooms? followed by any possible text string with any possible text between "hotel/" and "/rooms?".

I have this much:  ^/hotel/([^/])+/rooms([^\?])

But I'm not sure how to finish this so that it will only capture URLs that have text after the "?"

Answer (score 0):

This works. You may want to tighten up the the allowed text in the path parameter and query parameter.

```
^www.site.com/hotel/[^/]+/rooms\?.+$
```

Comment: Great. You can consider voting or accepting my answer ;)